# C# Visual Studio cannot add reference to 2 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello guys need some help :)

I have Initially, I had a single project, now I have to split it into multiple subprojects, however, I encountered an issue :(

Below is represented the structure of my (already splitted) solution:

> MySolution
>      -AppProject
>      -Project1(type classLibrary)
>      -Project2(type
>   classLibrary)

"AppProject" should contain the reference to both "Project1" and "Project2".
When I add "Project1" as the reference to "AppProject", everything is fine.

But when I add "Project2", happens the following:

1. AppProject sees Project2
2. AppProject doesn't see Project1 anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "see"? Does "Project1" reference "Project2" or vice versa?

Comment: Just a guess, but could you be getting class name / namespace conflicts between the two dependant libraries?  If so, you would start to get errors saying that previously resolves classes were now ambiguous.

Comment: In my solution I have 3 projects, AppProject is the one which uses functionality from Project1 and Project2. But when I add reference to both of them AppProject can only "see" classes from Project1 or Project2. By "see" I mean that the namespace is not visible

Comment: The actual question was if there is any relation from project 1 to project 2? Does one of them reference the other one?

Comment: pm_2 thank you for an idea, I will try to look for these conflicts

Comment: Make sure the namespaces of all three projects are different. If they are same, it might cause ambiguity

Comment: yes, Project2 uses some utilities from Project1